# I need to cut strings from a line(xml file) and save them in an array

Tags: python, xml, string, list, split

i have another question regarding python. I need to save a specific string of a xml file(the string appears several times in the file) in a list.

```
def parse_xml(self):
    file_ = open("ErrorReactions_TestReport_20160831_165153.xml", "r")
    for line in file_:
        line.rstrip()
        if "result_str" in line:
            if line == "Skipped":
                "count how much test cases are skipped"
            elif  line == "Failed"
                "count how much test cases failed
            else:
                "count how much test cases passed"
```

This is my code, my problem is that i need to save the string behind the parameter result_str and check if they match with "Skipped" or "Failed". How do i get that string saved in a variable?
The lines look like this:

< verdict time="1472654306.7" result_str="Passed" result="2">Generator run successfully< /verdict>
< verdict time="1472654306.7" result_str="Skipped" result="0" final="True">Testgenerator not active< /verdict>

Comment: use parser (ie `lxml`) or regex (ie. `result_str="([^"]*)"`)

Comment: or `if "result_str=\"Skipped\"" in line: result = "Skipped"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is one of many ways of doing this. I'm sure there are excellent tried and tested XML parsers out there though. This code will print `Passed`:

```
import re

line='''< verdict time="1472654306.7" result_str="Passed" result="2">Generator run successfully< /verdict> < verdict time="1472654306.7" result_str="Skipped" result="0" final="True">Testgenerator not active< /verdict>'''

p = re.compile(r'.*?result_str="(.*?)"')
match = p.match(line)
print(match.group(1))
```